# How to create two lists on Web Service simultaneously

Tags: c#, web-services, list

I'm developing an application that's using two lists returned from Web Service. I'm creating those lists in the Global.asax Application_Start event. My code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            WebService WS = new WebService();
            if(WS.PrzeslijCzyZrobMD5() == true)
            {
                WS.RecursiveFileProcessor();
            }
            else
            {
                WS.StworzListeMetodaDlugosci();
            }

        });
    }
```

RecursiveFileProcessor is a WebMethod that creates a list of files with their MD5 hashes. It takes up to 80 seconds for it to create. StworzListeMetodaDlugosci is a WebMethod that creates a list of files with their length and it takes 1 second for it to create.

In the start of my application I choose by which method I want to compare files. My goal is to have both of these lists simultaneously loaded just after the start of Web Service, because I want to use the length method list while I'm waiting for the MD5 one.

The point is that the lists should return null if they're not full. (For example, if there are 100 files in folder, WebMethod should return null if the list is not filled with all 100 files and return the list if it's filled with all 100 files).

This method returns the list to my app:

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<string> returnMD5List()
    {

        if (returnNullForList== true)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return FilesInWSList;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to spawn/use-thread-pools inside a web app due to IIS nuking your AppPool during what it thinks are _idle_ periods.  Plus it's harmful to kittens

Comment: So what's wrong with the method you've shown? I'd just set list when it is complete, but flag like you've shown (`if (returnNullForList) return null;`) is reasonable too.

Comment: I'm using bool to choose which list to create at the moment, but when I'm not using this bool and it's creating both lists, I have to wait until the longer one is created and I can't access the fast one by that moment.